# What is the best settings in handbrake for 640x480?

Tags: handbrake

I tried the default setting of the handbrake but generated video's size get greater than the original video itself. My video files are generally in between 100mb and 1.5Gb

I was wondering is it possible to detect the size before starting comprassion in `handbrake` and what is the best settings in `handbrake` for 640x480?

---

My current setup is as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can certainly do is lower the bitrate. 23 is quite a high bitrate, even more so for a h.264 .mp4. You should get away with a bitrate of 5-7. Also, you're encoding using the preset of 720p, which would be 1280×720 pixels. However, you stated that your resolution is only 640x480, so matching those settings will do a great deal in filesize aswell.

Comment: A lower RF produces a *larger* file. Roughly, an increase of RF by 6 reduces size by half.

Comment: of course, thank you for pointing this out. I edited my answer accordingly.